MySQL Full-Text search uncontrolled sort
MySQL 8.0.34
The following full-text search query didn't sort data according to relevance, please advise how I can control sorting on relevance. (script to create the table, insert data is in the bottom)
SELECT
    `platform`.`sample_search`.`name`,
        `platform`.`sample_search`.`search` 
FROM
    `platform`.`sample_search`
WHERE
    1=1
    AND MATCH (`platform`.`sample_search`.`search`) AGAINST ('+steve*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY
    MATCH (`platform`.`sample_search`.`search`) AGAINST ('+steve*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) DESC
LIMIT 50;

In lines 31 and 41 data is the same but not displayed together in sort sequence.

-- create table
CREATE TABLE sample_search (
    name varchar(191) CHARACTER
    SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    search text CHARACTER
    SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
    FULLTEXT KEY contacts_search_idx (search)) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

-- insert data
INSERT INTO sample_search (name,search) VALUES
    ('Steve Stevenson','steve st_ stevenson'),
    ('Steve Tussing','steve st_ tussing tu_'),
    ('Steve Gousing','steve st_ gousing go_'),
    ('Stephani Kobayashi Stevenson','stephani st_ kobayashi ko_ stevenson'),
    ('STEVEi LUCCHESI','stevei st_ lucchesi lu_'),
    ('Dost 2','dost do_ steve st_'),
    ('Steve Gous','steve st_ gous go_'),
    ('Dost 3','dost do_ steve st_ gousing go_'),
    ('steve bik rye','steve st_ bik bi_ rye ry_'),
    ('HOPPENFELD STEVE','hoppenfeld ho_ steve st_');

INSERT INTO sample_search (name,search) VALUES
    ('MASHING Steveston','mashing ma_ steveston st_'),
    ('bik steve rye','bik bi_ steve st_ rye ry_'),
    ('gousing steve','gousing go_ steve st_'),
    ('steve gouslo rye','steve st_ gouslo go_ rye ry_'),
    ('steve rye gouslo','steve st_ rye ry_ gouslo go_'),
    ('gouslo steve rye','gouslo go_ steve st_ rye ry_'),
    ('gouslo rye steve','gouslo go_ rye ry_ steve st_'),
    ('gouslo rye steve','gouslo go_ rye ry_ steve st_'),
    ('steve gousing rye','steve st_ gousing go_ rye ry_'),
    ('steve rye gousing','steve st_ rye ry_ gousing go_');

INSERT INTO sample_search (name,search) VALUES
    ('rye steve gousing','rye ry_ steve st_ gousing go_'),
    ('stevel gousingy','stevel st_ gousingy go_'),
    ('gousing steve rye','gousing go_ steve st_ rye ry_'),
    ('gousing rye steve','gousing go_ rye ry_ steve st_'),
    ('bik rye steve','bik bi_ rye ry_ steve st_ qa qa_'),
    ('co stevel','co co_ stevel st_ qa qa_'),
    ('cop rye stevel','cop co_ rye ry_ stevel st_ qa qa_'),
    ('Dost','dost do_ steve7_at_packagex_d_xyz st_ steve7 packagex pa_ at_packagex_d_xyz a undefined_at_packagex_d_xyz un packagex_d_xyz qa qa_'),
    ('Steve Ali','steve st_ ali al_ jonathan jo_'),
    ('Stevel','stevel st_ jonathan jo_');

INSERT INTO sample_search (name,search) VALUES 
    ('steve','steve st_ jonathan jo_ ali al_'),
    ('stevel gousingy','stevel st_ gousingy go_'),
    ('steve rye gouslo','steve st_ rye ry_ gouslo go_'),
    ('gouslo steve rye','gouslo go_ steve st_ rye ry_'),
    ('gouslo rye steve','gouslo go_ rye ry_ steve st_'),
    ('steve gousing rye','steve st_ gousing go_ rye ry_'),
    ('steve rye gousing','steve st_ rye ry_ gousing go_'),
    ('rye steve gousing','rye ry_ steve st_ gousing go_'),
    ('gousing steve rye','gousing go_ steve st_ rye ry_'),
    ('gousing rye steve','gousing go_ rye ry_ steve st_');

INSERT INTO sample_search (name, search) VALUES
    ('steve', 'steve st_ jonathan jo_ ali al_');


Try printing out the relevance scores in a column. As far as I can see, all rows contain steve* only once, therefore their relevance scores should be exactly the same. Mysql can order the rows with the same order values in any arbitrary way  - usually the order it reads them from the disk.

If the relevance scores are close, MySQL may order the results differently than expected. So, you can combine MATCH ... AGAINST result with another criterion, like name.
SELECT
`platform`.`sample_search`.`name`,
`platform`.`sample_search`.`search`, 
MATCH (`platform`.`sample_search`.`search`) AGAINST ('+steve*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 
FROM
    `platform`.`sample_search`
WHERE
    1=1
    AND MATCH (`platform`.`sample_search`.`search`) AGAINST ('+steve*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY
    relevance DESC,
    `platform`.`sample_search`.`name` DESC
LIMIT 50;


Mysql will sort rows according to the relevance scores even if they are just close, but still different.
